# jQuery deleting cookies using cookies plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin to store some cookies:

https://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation

I was wondering how i would go about deleting all cookies with a certain prefix and/or delete all cookies that have a certain value.  I need this to be done once some user has completed their journey through my application.

For example i store the visible state of certain tables on a page like so:

```
    // check visible status of table and persist
$('div.dependant').each(function(){

    var $childCount = $(this).index('div.dependant');

    $(this).addClass('tableStatus' + $childCount);

    // get the value of the cookie
    var $tableStatus = $.cookies.get('tableStatus' + $childCount);

    // if variable not null
    if ($tableStatus) {
        if ($tableStatus == 'hidden') {
            $('.tableStatus' + $childCount).hide();             
        } else if ($tableStatus == 'visible') {
            $('.tableStatus' + $childCount).show();
        }
    }

});
```

So the cookies will be 'tableStatus0', 'tableStatus1' etc...

I could manually delete but there will be an unknown number of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here:

https://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation